# Import child component package with parent component package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package

I've seen some components used like example below

```
import Parent from 'Parent';

<Parent.Child/>
...or...
<Parent>
    <Parent.Child/>
</Parent>
```

How should I structure the package so that I can do this? Plus what should I call such structure?

Comment: @Jayce444 I want to accept as answer. Could you post it as answer please?

Comment: Alrighty, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is in [Here](http://medium.com/risan/react-component-with-dot-notation-7a9853dbf33b).

TL;DR, the parent is a regular component and the children are static properties of the parent class

If you want to do it for functional components, you can do something like:

```
function Child() {
  return <div>this is a child</div>
}

function Parent() {
  return <div>this is a parent</div>
}

Parent.Child = Child;  // assign the child as a property of the parent function

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent/>
      <Parent.Child/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @InyoungKim yes there's an option for that, I'll add it to my answer